# Pull images from web or store them in a folder?

Tags: android, image, web, storage

I'm messing around making a cooking recipe catalogue. Now I'm making a list of recipes of certain category. A little illustration:

```
-|-----------|-
-|           |
-| Thumbnail |     RECIPE NAME RECIPE NAME RECIPE NAME RECIPE NAME
-|   Image   |
-|           |
-|-----------|-
```

What I would like to learn about is whether it is more useful to pull images from web or store them in a folder.
Storing them in a folder is much easier, I guess. But does it pay off, if the downloadable app's size is huge? With downloading the data maybe it is possible to only download the data of the categories you are watching?

You can come out with your own solutions as well.

I hope you get my point...

Comment: You can download images from the web and cache them for later use

Comment: I guess it depends how much categories you want to have in your applications. The tradeoff with downloading the images is that : 1. If your user does not have internet on, he will not be able to see the thumbnail unless you cached it in some way. 2. You are going to force the user to use the internet connection of his phone/tablet. Remember that the users do not always have big data plan or might not want to use their dataplan to download your images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If targeted application is using Internet, go for fetching the images from web, it would make the application light-weight.

But, if your application is not using internet, and is locally executed, go for a local database, and keep sizes as low as possible.

Also, to fetch from internet, you can do it in a efficient way, by not downloading the image and displaying it.
Alternatively, you can directly show image from web without downloading it. Please check the below function . It will show the images from the web into your image view.

```
public static Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        return d;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

then set image to imageview using code in your activity.